# PHP Multiarray Sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering how i can sort a multidimensional array.
My Array looks like this:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { [name"]=> string(8) "name one" ["price"]=> string(4) "3.99" ["image"]=> string(122) "..." ["updated_at"]=> string(13) "1511248800000" } 
    [1]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(8) "name two" ["price"]=> string(4) "2.42" ["image"]=> string(122) "..." ["updated_at"]=> string(13) "1511248800000" }
    [2]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(10) "name three" ["price"]=> string(4) "2.42" ["image"]=> string(122) "..." ["updated_at"]=> string(13) "1511248800000" }
    [3]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(9) "name four" ["price"]=> string(4) "2.42" ["image"]=> string(122) "..." ["updated_at"]=> string(13) "1511248800000" }
}
```

I want to sort it by price. How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: get the price column values with `array_column()`, sort that array and use its keys to sort the original array